# What word could be used to mean "legacy" of something that did not already exist?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am an ecologist writing a paper about disturbed forests (i.e. forests that are affected by things like forest fires, insects, and pathogens). It is common in my field to use the term "material legacy" to describe "stuff" that is left behind after a disturbance (like the seeds that remain after a wild fire). The word "legacy" implies that the materials in question existed pre-disturbance and then persisted afterwards; however, I am trying to come up with a term that describes structures that were not there before the disturbance, but are actually *generated* by the disturbance.

I've jokingly been using "spawn," but I don't think that will fly in a publication. I've also tested out "material currency" but I'm not sure if that's quite it either. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly 'mutation' (a brought-about change) in the general sense would do ... but of course genetics has largely hijacked the term.

Comment: What's wrong with "new material" or "new structures"? Using simple, well-understood terms is usually the best way to go.

Comment: How about "new ecosystem states" as found in this relevant article: https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/fee.1311

Comment: "Material legacy" does both describe what's left behind after a disturbance, and imply the material existed before.

However, structures that were not there before, but actually generated by the disturbance would not be antonymous; merely different.

Could you re-phrase the Question to ignore or explain how what you describe could be an antonym of "legacy"?

Comment: Afaik, you can use legacy to describe the effects of something that didn't pre-exist as well.

Comment: 'The word "legacy" implies that the materials in question existed pre-disturbance'. This is simply untrue - it only implies that it exists after the disturbance. If you want to describe items that are the legacy of the pre-disturbance landscape, you have to make that clear with extra words. We don't say that the wheel is a legacy of WWII, do we?

Comment: I would think that nothing that comes from the disturbance could possibly be the first of its kind. Nature revives over and over with the same mechanisms it always does. Nothing we can point to could be the first of its kine.

Comment: Legacy is commonly used of things that don't currently exist but will be created in future, e.g. "[Olympic legacy](https://olympics.com/ioc/olympic-legacy)"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use other phrases like "disturbance contribution" or "residual effects" or "permanent changes" that could convey various nuances of meaning - as opposed to "material legacy" (that you essentially define as "unaffected residue").

Answer (score 1):

You might use '***consequential***' to include those things that *"were not there before the disturbance, but are actually generated by the disturbance"*.

So,perhaps, ***consequential fallout***, where *fallout* is understood as

> *the (typically adverse or unexpected) consequences of an action or event* (OED)

Answer (score 0):

When speaking about materials that exist in the current point in time you can use the word "contemporary" (i.e. contemporary material). Conveniently, it also works when speaking about something in the past tense so long as the point in time is not ambiguous.

If you are fine with compound words, I would honestly just go with "post-disturbance" material, as it is clear, unambiguous, and uses terminology that is already defined.

It's not clear whether you're looking for a noun or an adjective, but it you're looking for a noun then you can probably use a more anthropomorphic term like "progeny".

Answer (score 0):

"Materialise" or "materialised" will do nicely. ["Materialise"](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/materialise) means come into being; become reality.

Another phrase ["churned out"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/churn-out) can also be used. To churn out something means to produce large quantities of it very quickly.